# How to use Ansible to ensure server maintains specified state?

Tags: ansible

I know Puppet can be used to keep the server in the consistent state. So for instance if someone else (perfectly legally) created a new user "bob", Puppet would spot this is not how the specification should be and then delete user "bob".

Is there a similar way to do this in Ansible?

Answer (score 2):

By default Ansible is designed to work in "push" mode, ie you actively send instructions to servers to do something.
However, Ansible also has `ansible-pull` command. I'm quoting from http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_intro.html#ansible-pull

---

> ## Ansible-Pull
>
> Should you want to invert the architecture of Ansible, so that nodes
>   check in to a central location, instead of pushing configuration out
>   to them, you can.
>
> Ansible-pull is a small script that will checkout a repo of
>   configuration instructions from git, and then run ansible-playbook
>   against that content.
>
> Assuming you load balance your checkout location, ansible-pull scales
>   essentially infinitely.
>
> Run `ansible-pull --help` for details.
>
> There’s also a [clever playbook](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/language_features/ansible_pull.yml) available to configure
>   ansible-pull via a crontab from push mode.